# Replacing One-Hot Encoding with Ordinal Encoding

Tags: python, scikit-learn, categorical-data, feature-engineering, ordinal

As an example, I have a dataset of available games.

```
Game A graphics presets are: Low, Medium, High, Ultra
Game B graphics presets are: Minimum, Balanced, Maximum
Game C graphics presets are: Ultra
```

One-hot encoding does not correctly position feature values and sometimes they mix up. Game A might not have the required feature scaling (other than presets) from Game B, therefore, using a **global model** (not a model per game) is essential.

Graphics preset is an **ordinal categorical column**.

Should a custom ordinal encoder encode features like:

```
Game A: 1, 2, 3, 4
Game B: 1, 2.5, 4
Game C: 2.5
```

or

```
Game A: 1, 2, 3, 4
Game B: 1, 2, 3
Game C: 1
```

Comment: you can use apply metod and set number. I use this.